# How to draw Open GL Elements more efficienty

Tags: android, performance, object, opengl-es-2.0

I've posted my drawing method which is called each frame.

I change the vertices each frame to move the object (which is basically a sprite/textured quad).

As you can see I was initially creating an array each frame, but I have changed this now and I create the array initially and just update it every frame, however I'm wondering if I can do anything more to improve the efficiency? (Although I'm getting about 90fps the sprite does not move smoothly all the time, every now and then it just pauses for a split second).  I can't see garbage collector running but I'm guessing it's due to allocation).

As I add more sprites/quads the jerkiness gets worse, but event at 100+ quads, although the smoothness has all but gone, my frame rate is still around 60fps so I can't understand what is slowing this down?

I've also added a screencap from Allocation Tracker

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void drawTest(float x, float y, float[] mvpMatrix){

//Convert Co-ordinates

//Left
xPlotLeft = (-MyGLRenderer.ratio)+((x)*MyGLRenderer.coordStepAmountWidth);
//Top
yPlotTop = +1-((y)*MyGLRenderer.coordStepAmountHeight);
//Right
xPlotRight = xPlotLeft+((quadWidth)*MyGLRenderer.coordStepAmountWidth);
//Bottom
yPlotBottom = yPlotTop-((quadHeight)*MyGLRenderer.coordStepAmountHeight);


//    Following has been changed as per below. I am now declaring the array initially and just updating it every frame.
//  float[] vertices = {

        //Top Left
//          xPlotLeft,yPlotTop,0, 0,0,
        //Top Right
//          xPlotRight,yPlotTop,0, 1,0,
        //Bottom Left
//          xPlotLeft,yPlotBottom,0, 0,1,
        //Bottom Right
//          xPlotRight,yPlotBottom,0, 1,1
//          };

vertices[0]=xPlotLeft;
vertices[1]=yPlotTop;
vertices[2]=0;
vertices[3]=0;
vertices[4]=0;

vertices[5]=xPlotRight;
vertices[6]=yPlotTop;
vertices[7]=0;
vertices[8]=1;
vertices[9]=0;

vertices[10]=xPlotLeft;
vertices[11]=yPlotBottom;
vertices[12]=0;
vertices[13]=0;
vertices[14]=1;

vertices[15]=xPlotRight;
vertices[16]=yPlotBottom;
vertices[17]=0;
vertices[18]=1;
vertices[19]=1;

 vertexBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
 vertexBuf.put(vertices).position(0);
    //GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
//Bind texture
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);      
//Use program
GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
// Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix2, 0, mvpMatrix, 0,  mRotationMatrix, 0);
// get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");
    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix2, 0);
    //Set starting position for vertices (0 for position)
vertexBuf.position(0);
//Specify attributes for vertex
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
//Enable attribute for position
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);
//Set starting position for vertices (3 for texture)
vertexBuf.position(3);
//Specify attributes for vertex
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
//Enable attribute for texture
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);
//Enable Alpha blending and set blending function
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//Draw
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
//Disable Alpha blending
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

}

[image]

Comment: As suggested in [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16000500/21727), have you tried this on other hardware, to see if under specced hardware is the problem?

Comment: @mbeckish yes, it works a better on a Nexus 10. However I don't understand that the fps is still 60, Does this not mean it should be smooth? Or am I misunderstanding that? I can understand if the FPS was dropping to 15 or so. Also I'm getting issues on a Galaxy Ace which, although, not a fantastically specced handset, should be able to handle 1 quad perfectly every time with no stops and starts (no matter how small)? I'd estimate my game will need about 80 sprites, so this is a problem! Can you see anything in my code that I'm doing 'inefficiently' or that could be done better?, Thanks –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` allocates a new buffer in memory every frame, you can create an initial buffer and overwrite the contents instead. Just use [`rewind()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind%28%29) or [`position(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) before `put()`.

To improve matters further, use a VBO (vertex buffer object, there are many tutorials online, and several questions on SO on this topic) and [`glBufferSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) to update the buffer.

Comment: This is awesome - thanks I moved the vertexBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect line to my constructor and put the rewind() line before put() as suggested and it's made so much difference.  I'm able to draw around 30-40 sprites now before I notice any pauses or slowdown (previously it was 1 sprite), thanks! Regarding VBO's I will post another question as I do have a VBO routine, but it doesn't seem to give me any performance increase over this routine, so maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: the bufferData method have a bug in some android versions which causes the buffer to be recreated constantly, you can read a bit about that here: http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/wiki/TalkTranscript